# c# LINQ) how to delete rows which match a List and specific value in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, list, datatable

I have DataTable with data as below,

```
Couponid       STATE

20160406000033     A  
20160406000051     A     <--- I don't want this row
20160406000051     K   
20160406000051     K
```

And I have a List list_coupon which include 20160406000051.

Now, I want to copy the whole DataTable only excluding rows which match the List list_coupon and have 'A' value simultaneously.
If the Couponid matches the list and value is 'K', it has to stay in DataTable.

To explain in another way,

While processing every row,

if a row doesn't belong to the list, this row has to stay in DataTable.

However, if a row belongs to the list, and if the row has 'A' value, this row has to be excluded but other rows belonging to the list with 'K' value have to stay in DataTable.

I did this by using couples of loop but it took too much time..

And I think below code which I tried divides the DataTable as rows belong to the list or not whereas I need rows which 'both belong and doesn't belong' to the list as well..

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows_query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  where !list_coupon.Contains(r.Field<string>("Couponid")) &&
                                  r.Field<string>("STATE") != "A"
                                  select r;

dt = rows_query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Your excellent advice will be highly appreciated !

Thank you so much !

Comment: If answer worked for you , please accept the answer.

Comment: @Viplock, someting is strange...and I'm analyzing..please wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your explanation I understood you want every row which is not in the list **OR** is in the list but with value different from A.

You need to use or operator in linq `||`.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows_query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  where !list_coupon.Contains(r.Field<string>("Couponid")) || 
                                  (list_coupon.Contains(r.Field<string>("Couponid")) &&
                                     r.Field<string>("STATE") != "A")
                                  select r;

if(rows_query.Any())
    dt = rows_query.CopyToDataTable();
```

It is good to check if there is any rows, because `CopyToDataTable()` will throw exception if no rows are returned from the linq.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your excellent knowledges ! It works fine !

Comment: Furthermore, could you kindly provide SQL statement which do the same meaning to delete rows if belong to list & have value 'A' ?

Comment: @KayLee Policy of stack overflow is to ask one question per post. Ask another one and someone will answer you.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the query to

```
  IEnumerable<DataRow> rows_query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                              where !(list_coupon.Contains(r.Field<string>("Couponid")) &&
                              r.Field<string>("STATE") == "A")
                              select r;

  dt = rows_query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Keep the not operator out of both and it will work smoothly .

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I also want to express my deep appreciation for your excellent knowledges..Please kinldy understand both answer are right but the other answer was provided earlier..

Comment: Furthermore, could you kindly provide SQL statement which do the same meaning to delete rows if belong to list & have value 'A' ?

Comment: That's very much fine, i was not asking to to accept my answer . I was asking to accept any answer  which was proper and satisfy you. 
:)